# using Math.Truncate to two decimals

Tags: c#

I have this number: 11,806.206193333.

I was using Math.Truncate(val * 100) / 100 to hopefully change to 11,806.20.

But the outsome came out to be 11806.00. What went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This should, and does, work. Can you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: Have you checked if the number is in a variable of type decimal, float, or double?

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is correct.  This works perfectly:

```
decimal val = 11806.206193333m;
decimal truncated =  Math.Truncate(val * 100) / 100;

Console.WriteLine("{0:N2}", truncated);
```

This will print `11,806.20` (on a US-English system).